# conditional operator warning

Tags: swift, conditional-operator

I get a warning that `will never be executed` with the following code

**Code:**

```
func f1()
{
    var a1 : Int = 100

    a1 = 1

    var a2 = (a1 > 40 ? 1 : 0) //No warning

    var a3 = (a1 > 40 ? "aaa" : "bbb") //Warning - will never be executed (points to "aaa")
}
```

**Questions:**

- I know based on the above logic, `a3` will get the value `"bbb"` but should there be a 
  warning ?
- Why is there no warning for evaluating the value of `a2`
- How can the compiler actually evaluate this ? I thought the values would be determined at runtime. (notice that the value of `a1` is changed after assignment)

Comment: I don't get any warning in playground.

Comment: I created a OS X > Command line tool project and I get that warning

Comment: I don't get a warning in a Command Line tool either. What version of Xcode are you using and is this the only code in the main.swift file?

Comment: Accept the answer if it cleared your mind. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var a3 = (a1 > 40 ? "aaa" : "bbb") //Warning
```

The reason why there is a warning on the line, because it actually calls some code. It is constructing a String instance by calling String's init().

```
a1 > 40 ? 1 : 0
```

This don't have any warning because it is primitive value, which not involve any init() or instance creation etc.

Things got interesting..

```
    func f1()
    {
        struct F {
            init(x: Int){
            }
        }

        var a1 : Int = 100

        a1 = 1

        var a2 = (a1 > 40 ? Int(1) : Int(0))      // No Warning

        var a4 = (a1 > 40 ? Int(Int(1) + UInt8(2)) : Int(0)) // Warning

        var a3 = (a1 > 40 ? String("aaa") : "bbb")  // Warning

        var a5: F = (a1 > 40 ? F(x: a2) : F(x: a1))  // Warning
    }
```

Why a3 and a5 got warning, it can be explained. But why a2 has no warning, it is calling Int(1), which should call struct Int's init(). The reason for that is "**Compiler optimization**". a4 has warning, which indicates the swift compiler's optimization is relative shallow. :)

## EDIT

From the generated code, you can see the difference. For simple Int(0), the struct's init not called.

```
   var a = Int(0)

   0x1006946d0:  pushq  %rbp
   0x1006946d1:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
   0x1006946d4:  subq   $0x20, %rsp
   0x1006946d8:  movq   %rdi, -0x10(%rbp)
   0x1006946dc:  movq   %rdi, -0x18(%rbp)
-> 0x1006946e0:  movq   $0x0, -0x8(%rbp)
   0x1006946e8:  callq  0x1006b0f14               ; symbol stub for: objc_release
   0x1006946ed:  addq   $0x20, %rsp
   0x1006946f1:  popq   %rbp
   0x1006946f2:  retq   

   var a2 = Int(Int(0x0) + UInt8(0xE))

   0x1007175f0:  addq   $0x8, %rax
   0x1007175f6:  movq   0x1ebc3(%rip), %r8        ; (void *)0x0000000104a89d88: protocol witness table for Swift.UInt8 : Swift.Strideable
   0x1007175fd:  movq   0x1eaac(%rip), %rcx       ; (void *)0x0000000104a92f80: direct type metadata for Swift.Int
   0x100717604:  addq   $0x8, %rcx
   0x10071760b:  movq   0x1eb5e(%rip), %rdx       ; (void *)0x0000000104a8b228: protocol witness table for Swift.Int : Swift.SignedNumberType
   0x100717612:  movq   0x1eb67(%rip), %rsi       ; (void *)0x0000000104a8b0c8: protocol witness table for Swift.Int : Swift._BuiltinIntegerLiteralConvertible
   0x100717619:  leaq   -0x38(%rbp), %r9
   0x10071761d:  leaq   -0x30(%rbp), %r10
   0x100717621:  leaq   -0x28(%rbp), %r11
   0x100717625:  movq   %rdi, -0x18(%rbp)
   0x100717629:  movq   %rdi, -0x20(%rbp)
-> 0x10071762d:  movq   $0xb, -0x28(%rbp)
   0x100717635:  movb   $0xe, -0x30(%rbp)
   0x100717639:  movq   %rdi, -0x40(%rbp)
   0x10071763d:  movq   %r9, %rdi
   0x100717640:  movq   %rsi, -0x48(%rbp)
   0x100717644:  movq   %r11, %rsi
   0x100717647:  movq   %rdx, -0x50(%rbp)
```

Comment: Both Int and String are struct in Swift. Try the following code: `var a2 = (a1 > 40 ? Int(1) : Int(0)) //No warning` So both call the initialiser / constructor yet there is no warning for Int, while there is a warning for String

Comment: a2 and a3 are similar yet there is no warning for a2 and there is a warning for a3. Both use constructors / initialisers. And a4 has a warning ... makes it more interesting (confusing)

Comment: @user1046037 That is where Compiler optimization comes in. Swift compiler tries to generate performant code, so it removes the Int()'s init. You can read the generated assembly if interested.

Comment: @user1046037 Open a new question?